# How to inject conditional checks before execution of any class methods

Tags: javascript, typescript, oop, asynchronous

I'm looking for some opinions / solutions on how to handle async data retrieval gracefully.

In initializing any class with some data asynchronously, I've been taking the approach like so:

```
class SomeClass {
  // Turning off ts compiler's strictPropertyInitialization
  private someProperty: SomeType 

  public async init(): Promise<this> {
    this.someProperty = await goAndGetDataFromWhoKnowsWhere();
    return this;
  }

  public async aMethod(): Promise<AType> {
    // do its thing
  }

  public async anotherMethod(): Promise<AnotherType> {
    // do its thing
  }
}
```

And expect the user (myself / another co-worker) to use this class like so:

```
const someResult = new SomeClass()
  .init()
  .then( thatClass => thatClass.aMethod() )
```

This approach sure serves the purpose okay, but there're no hard restrictions to make sure the `init()` is getting called. Sometimes when someone forgets about it things break.

We could probably turn on the `strictPropertyInitialization` and inject checking in every single class method. That'd work for sure but the identical lines in the methods are yelling that there's probably a better way.

```
class SomeClass {
  private someProperty: SomeType | undefined // To enforce null-checking

  public async init(): Promise<this> {
    this.someProperty = await goAndGetDataFromWhoKnowsWhere();
    return this;
  }

  public async aMethod(): Promise<AType> {
    if (!this.someProperty) await this.init();
    // do its thing
  }

  public async anotherMethod(): Promise<AnotherType> {
    if (!this.someProperty) await this.init();
    // do its thing
  }
}
```

Are there any solutions to this problem? Any design patterns that work around this problem? Helps appreciated! :)

Comment: Is the question, was init() called in the chain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you thought about not exposing the `new()` constructor call at all?  What if you make the constructor `private`, and expose a static `init()` method that asynchronously constructs an instance and fills it with the data:

```
class SomeClass {

  static async init(): Promise<SomeClass> {
    return new SomeClass(await goAndGetDataFromWhoKnowsWhere());
  }

  private constructor(private someProperty: SomeType) {  }

  // your other methods    
}


new SomeClass("oops"); // can't do this

SomeClass.init().then(thatClass => thatClass.aMethod());
```

Now it's essentially impossible for anyone to use this the wrong way.  Hope that gives you some ideas.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Another option is you could wrap creation of the class in a function. Assuming `init` must be called on every instance, you could just handle that on creation:

<sub>(Sorry it's not in TypeScript; I'm just not as familiar with it.)</sub>

```js
const goAndGetDataFromWhoKnowsWhere = async () => 123;

const SomeClass = () => {
  class SomeClass {
    async init() {
      this.someProperty = await goAndGetDataFromWhoKnowsWhere();
      return this;
    }
  }
  return new SomeClass().init();
};

SomeClass().then(inst => {
  console.log('someProperty:', inst.someProperty);
});
```

Similar to [jcalz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55348598/8550747) this would not allow use with the `new` keyword:

```
new SomeClass(); // TypeError: SomeClass is not a constructor
```

Answer (score 0):

How about just using a function instead?

```
function SomeClass(){
  var newObj = Object.create(/* your prototype */)
  return goAndGetDataFromWhoKnowsWhere()
  .then((data) => {
    newObj.someProperty = data;
    return newObj;
  })
}

SomeClass().then((newObj) => {})
```